# Java Recursive Method ArrayList is not adding all child elements to the final ArrayList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I am writing a recursive method which traverse a hierarchy of Java objects. For this purpose I wrote a recursive method which takes the root node(parent) as parameter. Here is the base method which calls recursive method traverse:

```
if (category.id == GALLERIE_ID_TEST) {
                traverse(category);
                System.out.println("children ...." + subCategories);
            }
```

And in the traverse method I wrote a logic which traverses all the child nodes of my parent node. But when I add all the child objects to a ArrayList, all children are not getting added to the final list from this method. Its returning only the child count of parent node but I need to get all the child nodes of the subsequent nodes too.

Here my code goes:

```
private static void traverse(KalturaCategory category)
        throws KalturaApiException {
    List<KalturaCategory> subCategories = new ArrayList<KalturaCategory>();
    KalturaCategoryListResponse categoriesList = null;
    if (category != null && category.directSubCategoriesCount >= 1) {
        KalturaCategoryFilter filter = new KalturaCategoryFilter();
        filter.parentIdEqual = category.id;
        categoriesList = getCategoriesList(filter);
        if (categoriesList.totalCount != 0) {
            for (KalturaCategory subCat : categoriesList.objects) {
                traverse(subCat);
                subCategories.add(subCat);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("subCategories Size ------>"
                + subCategories.size());

    }

}
```

My output is:

```
subCategories Size ------>3
subCategories Size ------>4
subCategories Size ------>5
subCategories Size ------>5
subCategories Size ------>1
subCategories Size ------>6
children ....[]
```

But I want to get all this separate child objects into one ArrayList and return to my first method. Please help me resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure getCategoriesList() is behaving properly?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes its a standard structure which always returns results. Also I printed the values from this method too. Its returning:        categoriesList.totalCount ------>6
categoriesList.totalCount ------>3
subCategories Size ------>3
categoriesList.totalCount ------>4
subCategories Size ------>4
categoriesList.totalCount ------>5
subCategories Size ------>5
categoriesList.totalCount ------>5
subCategories Size ------>5
categoriesList.totalCount ------>1
subCategories Size ------>1
subCategories Size ------>6

Comment: Try swapping these two statements, `traverse(subCat);subCategories.add(subCat);`

Comment: I tried many solutions it includes this too ... swapping these two statements. Anyhow Its working now. I have declared the list as a global static variable which solved the problem. Thanks for your time giving solution.

Comment: If you have it working and you used an answer here, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Please tell me how to do that ... i tried but could not be able to...

Comment: You don't see a check-mark under the up/down arrows to the left of each answer?  You need to click on that check mark to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you recursion is getting a copy of your array and return nothing to the original parent array [pass by value].

Try moving your category list outside the function and make it a global/static variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution worked. Now the parent is returning the all child's as a single list.

Answer (score 0):

You might pass the single (!) List to receive all objects as a parameter in the recursive method:

```
private static void traverse(KalturaCategory category,
                             List<KalturaCategory> subCategories ) 
    throws KalturaApiException {
    if (category != null && category.directSubCategoriesCount >= 1) {
        KalturaCategoryFilter filter = new KalturaCategoryFilter();
        filter.parentIdEqual = category.id;
        KalturaCategoryListResponse categoriesList =
            getCategoriesList(filter);
        if( categoriesList.totalCount != 0) {
            for (KalturaCategory subCat : categoriesList.objects) {
                traverse(subCat, subCategories);
            }
            subCategories.addAll( categoriesList.objects );
        }
    }
}
```

Change the first call accordingly, with the root node:

```
List<KalturaCategory> subCategories = new ArrayList<KalturaCategory>();
traverse( category, subCategories );
```

and subCateogories contains all objects from all nodes in the hierarchy.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? You haven't posted enough code for a complete verifieable example.